# Flutter / Dart and AWS SDK

Tags: dart, aws-sdk, flutter

I am thinking of writing a mobile app in Flutter (which uses dart). However I heavily use AWS and not being able to use their SDK would be troublesome.

Is there any good way to make use of it? As far as I know there is not a Dart version of the SDK. I don't know if it's possible to interrop to other language's libs in Dart or something?

Is my best bet to use the REST apis maybe?

Comment: there is [this library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/aws_client) but not ready for production

Comment: What functionality are you trying to use from the AWS SDK?

Comment: Mostly Cognito right now, but I can probably use their REST api

Answer (score 6):

AWS announced a developer preview of AWS Amplify Flutter. It's not production-ready yet and it only contains auth, storage, and analytics for now. Check it out.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-aws-amplify-flutter-developer-preview/

Comment: Do you have any idea what about the Signer class to sign URLs? this is a must have in case we want to sign a URL. But it is not supported apparently yet with no official statements.

Comment: AWS Amplify Flutter is now GA. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amplify-flutter-is-now-generally-available-build-beautiful-cross-platform-apps/

Answer (score 4):

You probably can use a **MethodChannel** and write platform specific code (Android) using AWS SDKs.

Refer to [Platform Channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no official support for Flutter from AWS yet (March 2019)

BUT there is a community plugin that works perfectly fine on IOS and Android with Cognito and Sigv4 to access all AWS services securely.

Here are the details [amazon_cognito_identity_dart](https://medium.com/@wesselsbernd/flutter-and-aws-as-of-march-2019-1ad7f40fa9e4)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [example](https://read.acloud.guru/serverless-application-with-flutter-lambda-aa0d264fbefd) if you can use Amazon API Gateway. A REST call can be something like:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    http.get(this._apiGatewayURL)
        .then((response) => response.body)
        .then(json.decode)
        .then((movies) {
          movies.forEach(_addMovie);
        });
}
```