# How to download the file from the S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, agora.io

My requirement is to download the file from the s3 bucket,
I tried to make the bucket public, then I successfully downloaded the file using that s3 URL,

I'm using Agora Cloud Recording API for each screen recording Agora saves the videos in the s3 bucket successfully, then I need to download the file from the s3.

Agora suggest to make the bucket public, to download the file via s3 URL,
Because of the s3 security issue I don't want to make the bucket public, is there is any other way to download the file from the s3 bucket without making the bucket public?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter / Dart and AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618844/flutter-dart-and-aws-sdk)

Comment: this does not works

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin I can able to download the file:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_aws_s3_client